# bash script appending data after comma

Tags: bash, awk

I have a test file with following contents.

```
[groups]

test_read =  apple,orange
write = grapes,mango
[TEST:/]
@test_read= apple,orange
@write= grapes,mango
```

I need to add the word raspberry on all the fields under groups section which is above [TEST:/]

Expected output

```
[groups]

    test_read =  apple,orange,raspberry
    write = grapes,mango,raspberry
    [TEST:/]
    @test_read= apple,orange
    @write= grapes,mango
```

I tried with this one liner

```
awk 'NF > 1 {$NF = $NF ",raspberry"} 1' test
```

But it is adding raspberry on all the fields.

Comment: Why is the expected output? `tabbed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '/\[groups/{a=1;print;next} /^\[/{a=0}a && /=/{$0=$0",raspberry"}7' file
```

This line works no matter where is the `groups` block located. (E.g. is above or under the `TEST` block).

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks. can u please tell me how it works.

Comment: @catchvenki it searches the `[groups`, if this was found, I let awk know following lines till next `[..]` or EOF we should append the string to all lines containing `=`. when next `[..]` comes, we stop the appending logic.

Comment: HI kent, may i know how to redirect this output to the file. right now its only prints the proper output. but when i open the file the updated data is not there

Comment: `awk ... input > output.txt` or `awk ... inputF > tmp && mv tmp inputF` @catchvenki

Comment: for i in `cat file`;do awk '/\[groups/{a=1;print;next} /^\[/{a=0}a && /=/{$0=$0",raspberry"}7' $i; done . this is what i am trying. To append this in multiple files

Comment: But this doesnt append properly can you please help

Comment: @catchvenki  you didn't do any redirection like what I wrote in above comment, and it sounds another question.

Comment: hi kent, for i in `cat file`;do awk '/\[groups/{a=1;print;next} /^\[/{a=0}a && /=/{$0=$0",raspberry"}7' $i; done > $i . this is what i am trying . issue is file remains unchanged and file2 is copying the existing data and adding it one more time with appended output . seems like some issue with for loop.plz help

Comment: hi kent , found out the issue and resolved it. Thanks for your help. if i execute the script again, its keep on appending. is there any way we can check if the word raspberry is already there and should append if its not there.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/\[/{f=/groups/} f{if (NF) $0=$0",raspberry"} 1' file
[groups],raspberry

test_read =  apple,orange,raspberry
write = grapes,mango,raspberry
[TEST:/]
@test_read= apple,orange
@write= grapes,mango
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `sed` command:

```
sed '1,/\[TEST:\/\]/{/=/s/$/,raspberry/;}' file

[groups]

test_read =  apple,orange,raspberry
write = grapes,mango,raspberry
[TEST:/]
@test_read= apple,orange
@write= grapes,mango
```

To save the changes inline use:

```
sed -i.bak '1,/^[ \t]*\[TEST:\/\]/{/=/s/$/,raspberry/;}' file
```

**How it works:**

```
1,/^[ \t]*\[TEST:\/\]/  # search between 1st line and the line where [TEST:/] is found
{
   /=/                  # only act on line where = is found (fields)
   s/$/,raspberry/;     # replace end of line with ,raspberry 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` in `gawk`

```
awk 'f && /=/{$0=$0 ",raspberry"}
     match($0, /^\[([^\]]*)\]$/, a){f=(a[1]=="groups")}1' file
```

you get,

```
[groups]

test_read =  apple,orange,raspberry
write = grapes,mango,raspberry
[TEST:/]
@test_read= apple,orange
@write= grapes,mango
```