# Awk read and write to a set of files using for loop

Tags: bash, awk

I am reading and trying to append the changes to a set of files, but it is not working as expected. The output is printing perfectly but not appending in the set of files.

```
cat file
test
test1

for i in `cat file`;do
  awk '/\[groups/{a=1;print;next} /^\[/{a=0}a && /=/{$0=$0",raspberry"}7' $i;
done > $i.tmp && mv $i.tmp $i
```

kindly help.

Comment: Let's see some data and th expected output.

Comment: two problems: `i` ss outside the scope of the `for` ... and always use double quotes around variable substitutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming when you say `append the changes` you really mean `apply the changes`, this is how you'd do it with a loop and any awk:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
  awk '/\[groups/{a=1;print;next} /^\[/{a=0}a && /=/{$0=$0",raspberry"}7' "$i" > "$i.tmp" &&
  mv "$i.tmp" "$i"
done < file
```

but your awk command could be clearer and simpler, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41811423/1745001, and if you have GNU awk and GNU xargs you don't need the loop or tmp files:

```
xargs -d $'\n' < file awk -i inplace '/\[/{f=/groups/} f{if (NF) $0=$0",raspberry"} 1'
```

Comment: Hi morton 
works perfectly. thanks.But if i run the script again its appending one more time. is there anyway we can check whether raspberry is already there and if its not there append else exit.  plz help

Comment: Of course, checking for raspberry being present first would be trivial but why are you just mentioning that requirement now and what other requirements are you planning to give us one at a time? wrt xargs `showing some syntax error` - don't you think it'd be easier for us to help you debug that it you told us what the syntax error message was?